# Cannot build Docker image for Angular 12

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, docker

I an trying to build an Angular image but i'm getting this error:

```
#14 130.6 - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
#14 146.6 events.js:377
#14 146.6       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
#14 146.6       ^
#14 146.6
#14 146.6 Error: write EPIPE
#14 146.6     at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
#14 146.6     at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
#14 146.6     at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:787:11)
#14 146.6     at Socket._write (net.js:799:8)
#14 146.6     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
#14 146.6     at Socket.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
#14 146.6     at Object.writeToStdin (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1725:19)
#14 146.6     at sendRequest (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:617:14)
#14 146.6     at start (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1254:9)
#14 146.6     at Object.transform2 [as transform] (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1304:5)
#14 146.6 Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
#14 146.6     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
#14 146.6     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
#14 146.6     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
#14 146.6     at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)
#14 146.6     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:437:9) {
#14 146.6   errno: -32,
#14 146.6   code: 'EPIPE',
#14 146.6   syscall: 'write'
```

Here is my DockerFile:

```
#stage 1
FROM node:14.17.6 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod
#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/Angular /usr/share/nginx/html
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.1.2",
    "rating": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "firebase": "^9.4.0",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I am using Docker Desktop 4.4.4 for Windows

PS : I have already tried to incrase docker engine's memory and tried several versions of node but I have the same problem.

The application can run normally on my machine but only the Docker image cannot build.

Can any one help please?

Comment: Could you share your package.json ?

Comment: _"I have already tried to incrase docker engine's memory"_ Why?

Comment: @jeremy-denis I uptaded the post with the package.json

Comment: Are you using Windows? Does this solve your problem: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9077?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding this line in the DockerFile:

```
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
```

It seems that the problem occurs when launching e2e tests and Angular CLI is needes

DockefFile becomes:

```
#stage 1
FROM node:14.17.6 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod
#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/Angular /usr/share/nginx/html
```